# How do I add values of radio buttons to get a sum

Tags: jquery

I have some radio inputs in a form which I have written code for when selected. However, when I try to do addition I get NaN.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
    <label class="form-check-label ">
        <input class="form-check-input row1" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="r1" value="1">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label ">
        <input class="form-check-input row1" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="r2" value="2">
      </label>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
function sum(){

 var one = $('input:checked.row1').val();
 var two = $('input:checked.row2').val();
 var three = $('input:checked.row3').val();
 var four = $('input:checked.row4').val();
 var five = $('input:checked.row5').val();
 var six = $('input:checked.row6').val();
 var seven = $('input:checked.row7').val();
 var eight = $('input:checked.row8').val();
 var nine = $('input:checked.row9').val();

}
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: what mean by do addition?

Comment: convert the values into numbers you can use `Number()` or `parseFloat()`.. using radio button for adding is not user friendly radio button suppose to function to let user select only 1

Comment: Add as in one + two

Comment: @mpouzouxis : `one` is not an number. you need to set radio button value as `1` then parse it using `parseInt()` to get sum

Comment: HTML added. If I use either Number() or Parse and then do the math equation, I get NaN

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the example below.

This will get the value of all checked inputs and calculate the total value.

I've used `[class^=row]` so it will take the value from any `input` that is `checked` and also have a class that starts with `row`

**Note** if you want to short down the code even more (compared to the snippet below) use :

```
function sum() {
  var total = 0;
  var all = $('input:checked[class^=row]').map(function() {
    total += Number(this.value)
  })
}
```

```js
function sum() {
  var all = $('input:checked[class^=row]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(",");
  
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    total += all[i] << 0;
  }
  console.log(total)
}

$('input[class^=row]').change(function() {
  sum();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="row1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="row2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="row3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="row4" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="row5" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="row6" value="6" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each input selected then parse those value to int.

```
 function getsum() {
    var sum= 0;
      $('input:checked').each(function(){
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
      });
      return sum;
    }

alert(getsum());
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjpgq5fL/2/)**